# What is the alternative way of setting absoluteposition of a recordset on a server side recordset?

Tags: postgresql

In one of the existing codes in the project I am working on , AbsolutePosition property of the server side recordset has been used to set the current record in the recordset.

```
m_Record->AbsolutePosition = (enum PositionEnum)(row+1);
```

this worked fine on sql server. Now I am migrating to PostgreSQL which does not support absoluteposition unless its a client side recordset.

What workaround or alternative method can be used to achieve this

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: MFC code . m_Record is a Ado _RecordsetPtr